# TabHost: переключение между вкладками

Tags: android, java, android-studio

Я новичок, первый раз пишу на Android. Пытаюсь нарисовать TabHost. Приложение запускается, но сам TabHost не отображается. Помогите :>

Нужно отобразить **Main.xml** и **Three.xml**

1. Создал *Main.xml* и его класс *MainActivity.java*
2. Создал *Two.xml* и его класс *ActivityTwo.java*
3. Создал *Three.xml* и его класс *ActivityThree.java*
4. B **Three.xml** поставил TabHost
5. B **ActivityThree.java** написал:

   ```
   public class ActivityThree extends TabActivity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.three);

   TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

   TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;

   tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
   tabSpec.setIndicator("Вкладка1");
   tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
   tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

   tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
   tabSpec.setIndicator("Вкладка2");
   tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class));
   tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
   ```

В каком пункте ошибка?

Comment: TabHost уже устарел. Его никто не использует.    
Как сделать правильно, можно найти тут: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20tabs%20tutorial&es_th=1

Comment: "Приложение запускается" - какая Активити запускается при старте приложения? MainActivity? Но вы же не в ней добавили TabHost! С чего он в ней должен отображаться?